# copy a db table column and alter its type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table that looks like:

```
create_table "google_records", :force => true do |t|
 t.string   "user_id"
 t.string   "date"
 t.text     "stats"
 t.text     "account_name"
 t.datetime "created_at",                                       :null => false
 t.datetime "updated_at",                                       :null => false
 t.float    "total_cost",        :limit => 12, :default => 0.0, :null => false
 t.integer  "total_conversions",               :default => 0,   :null => false
end
```

I need to be able to query the db using group like `group('year(date)').group('month(date)')` but can not do that because my column type is string for date.

Rather than change the column type to datetime through a migration (because there is a lot of code on prod that uses it as string), I was thinking about adding a new column.

Is there an way to populate that new column by duping the current date column and then calling something like `date.to_datetime` on each field?

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Why would this be downvoted?  Just curious so I can avoid what I've done wrong in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strptime](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strptime/class) allows you to give a format and a string and it will output a datetime for you.

So create your new datetime column (in my example its :datetime_column), and then in your rails console

```
> all_records = GoogleRecord.all
> all_records.each {|r| r.update_attributes(datetime_column: Date.sprptime(r.date, "%Y-%m-%d"}
(or whatever your date format is in)
```

You might have to tool around with it as I haven't run any test cases, but let me know if there are any problems

Comment: Thanks JTG, small tweak though => `update` needs to be `update_attributes` otherwise you get a `NoMethodError (Attempt to call private method)`.  Otherwise, it worked great!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's no reason why you can't create a field and (in the migration itself) put in some Ruby code to fix this on the 'up' migration

```
reversible do |dir|
  dir.up { GoogleRecord.update_all_dates }
end
```

And define the `:update_all_dates` in the class to do just that.

You may also want to put a `before_save` callback in the Model so that every time a record is saved, `new_date` is updated with the value in `date`

```
class GoogleRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save :update_date

def self.update_all_dates
  all.each {|gr| gr.update_attribute(:new_date, Date.parse(gr.date)) }
end

private
def update_date
  self.new_date = Date.parse(date)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, I had already run the migration and had the new column but tried this on a tutorial app I had and it worked great.  I'll do it all in one next time!

Comment: I'd suggest you wrap the all.each update into a GoogleRecord class method. Then if someone does rake db:schema:load, they'll then be able to call that class method to update all the new_dates.

Comment: @ReggieB I've updated my answer with your corrected edit (which was inexplicably rejected by the review process!) so now fixed and thanks for that!  

I agree it feels like better code to have `update_all_dates` as a class method.  I also changed to use `update_attribute` which is a better way to update a single column.

But on db:schema:load you'll have an empty database anyway!

Comment: @SteveTurczyn good point about db:schema:load creating an empty database. My main point is that in my experience relying on logic in migration (beyond modification of SQL tables) being processed  almost always comes back to bite you on the bum. You cannot guarantee that logic in a migration will be run, so always package the logic up outside of the migration and then add a hook to the logic in the migration. So, I think your modified solution hits the mark perfectly.